# Different maps/views/lay-out in 1 project

Tags: qgis, layouts

I am looking for a option in QGIS to make different maps/views/layout in one project. I have made a map in AutoCAD of houses, roads and public space. I've set all the object in different layers so I can turn the objects on and off in QGIS.

I want to make different views with specific layers turned on/off without interacting with other views.

Lets say 1 map with only the houses, 1 with only the roads and 1 with only the public space in the same project.

Answer (score 8):

With QGIS 3 you can do this by creating a new map view (View--> New Map View). 
Then you can create 2+ map themes from your layer panel(eye icon -->add theme) and choose which one you want to use in each map view. 
 The maps scrolls and zooms in/out simultaneously as you move your cursor into the main map view. It's a great feature!!

Comment: Awesome feature!

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: Indeed, this works in QGIS 3 and allows us to work with multiple synchronized map views, composed of different layers.

Answer (score 4):

You can add several different style to the same layer (right click on a layer then Styles>Add... , you need to add a new style before modifying it)

After that you can define different theme (using the eyes icon at the top of the layer panel) that will define witch layer are visible or not and the style you want to display for each layer.

Then in your print layout you have the option for each map item to follow specific map theme

Answer (score 2):

If you mean something like [dataframes in ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/using-data-frames.htm), as I know, QGIS doesn't work in that way.

If what you mean by map/view/layout is layout for printing/exporting different layers of the map, "Project > Composer Manager..." in QGIS 2 ("Project > Layout Manager..." in QGIS 3) aims to perform that job. Look at "[Making a Map](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html#making-a-map)" for further information.